# Can I run a setup script when submitting a Dataflow job before running the pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm employing Apache Beam Python SDK 2.0.0 to define a pipeline and I'm trying to run it on the Google Cloud Dataflow.

The code uses the **gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin** for authentication purposes, but it requires installing some packages[1] via *apt-get* . So I need to run this code `sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev python-setuptools libffi-dev libssl-dev` before executing the pipeline.

How can I tell the Dataflow to execute this command in the VM before executing the job? I Know that we can specify a startup script for a Compute Engine, but in Dataflow this is created under the hood, can I do something analogous when submitting a job in Dataflow?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary

Answer (score 2):

***For Python Dependencies***

You can pass a `--requirements_file` argument when you submit your pipeline. This file should contain a line-separated list of `package==version`, just like the output of the `pip freeze` command.

***For non-Python dependencies***

In this case, you will need to pass a `--setup_file` argument to your pipeline. In the `setup.py` file, you add a call to `setuptools.setup`, in which you pass a `cmdclass` argument with classes that implement your installation logic. The Apache Beam repository contains an [example of this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py).

For more on this, check [Managing Pipeline Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python).

Comment: thanks for your help. I need to install packages via apt-get. I know that I can pass the `requirements.txt`, but how can I pass a setup script to install packages via `apt-get` when submitting a Dataflow job?

Comment: Here in the official Dataflow doc, it shows how to do that: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python#pypi-dependencies-with-non-python-dependencies